# MYSQL-how to insert geometry data

Tags: mysql, geometry

I'm trying to insert geometry data using MYSQL, here is a code-example:

```
CREATE TABLE CARTESIAN
(
ROW_ID INT NOT NULL,
G GEOMETRY,
PRIMARY KEY(ROW_ID)
)

INSERT INTO CARTESIAN
VALUES (0,'POINT(1 1)'), 
       (1,'LINESTRING(2 1, 6 6)'), 
       (2,'POLYGON((0 5, 2 5, 2 7, 0 7, 0 5))')
```

When I run the INSERT I receive the message "Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field".
Can you explain me where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to convert the text representations into `GEOMETRY` before you can insert them using the [`ST_GeomFromText`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_st-geomfromtext) function. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE CARTESIAN
(
ROW_ID INT NOT NULL,
G GEOMETRY,
PRIMARY KEY(ROW_ID)
);
INSERT INTO CARTESIAN
VALUES (0,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)')), 
       (1,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(2 1, 6 6)')), 
       (2,ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 5, 2 5, 2 7, 0 7, 0 5))'));
SELECT * FROM CARTESIAN
```

Output:

```
ROW_ID  G
0       [GEOMETRY - 25 B]
1       [GEOMETRY - 45 B]
2       [GEOMETRY - 97 B]
```

Comment: Yeah, now it runs. In my query result G has the values wrapped inside quotes ('POINT(1 1)' for example, not [GEOMETRY - 25 B]), but if I put the pointer on the value I can see the spatial results, so there is everything I was looking for. Thank you again!